# Amazon Certificate Manager gives LimitExceededException

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I have a fresh AWS account with no certificates connected to it.

This is what it looks like when I try to request a certificate for a domain through the Amazon Certificate Manager:

[image: Error message when requesting a certificate.[1]]

Trying the `aws acm request-certificate` command from the command line gives me:

```
An error occurred (LimitExceededException) when calling the 
RequestCertificate operation: Cannot request more certificates in this account. 
Contact Customer Service for details
```

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-limits.html) mention limits, but I have no certificates so I shouldn't have exceeded it.

[image]

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: I would open a case as suggested.  Is this a new account?  Did you specify > 10 domain names in the certificate? This limit is per certificate.

Comment: @RodrigoM I have opened a support case now, thought I would see if anyone else have had this problem.
It's a new account (a couple of weeks) but S3 and Billing is working fine.
I only requested one (naked) domain name.

Comment: Does `aws acm list-certificates` show anything?

Comment: @DusanBajic it gives me `{
    "CertificateSummaryList": []
}`

Comment: Well, really looks like a case for AWS support, let us know what happened.

Comment: Yes I have created two ACM certificates on a new account recently and had no issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was solved by AWS support, not sure what the actual issue was.

Comment: did you have to pay for support plan in order to be able to contact them about this? If not, what option should I choose when I open the ticket? Account and Billing?

Comment: no, increasing limits is available on the support ticket type regardless of your support level

Answer (score 9):

One thing that is not on most answers here. When you create an account and/or haven't used it much (the representative from aws' answer was unclear as to what constitutes a proper usage of the account in the beginning) your limit is actually 0.

So your choices here are request a limit increase or wait until it reaches some sort of adequate usage as required by AWS.

Comment: oh Bezos...Why?!

Answer (score 2):

If certs don't show on "aws acm list-certificates", that's because of the regions thing, most likely. This is the result with my default region:

```
hannah@Hannah-PC:~$ aws acm list-certificates
{
    "CertificateSummaryList": []
}
hannah@Hannah-PC:~$ grep region .aws/config 
region = ap-southeast-2
```

This is the result when I change the region to us-east-1:

```
hannah@Hannah-PC:~$ aws acm list-certificates --region=us-east-1
{
    "CertificateSummaryList": [
        {
            "CertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:31234512345:certificate/XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX",
            "DomainName": "whatever.net"
        }
    ]
}
```

SSL certs have to in us-east-1 specifically for CloudFront to use them.